# AngularJS $scope.$apply vs $q

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am having a little trouble understanding can someone explain what's the difference between this pieces of code :

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position){ //asychronous
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.position=position;
       });
   });
};
```

and this

```
function getPosition(){
  var deferred=$q.defer();
  if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position){
        deferred.resolve(position);
    })
  }return deferred.promise;
}

var promise=getPosition();
promise.then(function(position){
    $scope.position2=position;
})
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic thing that is going on here is the code is using a browser native API (`navigator.geolocation.watchPosition`) that angularjs doesn't have built-in support for. AngularJS supports most things directly (`$timeout`, `$window`, `$http`, `$location`, etc), but this particular thing isn't baked in to angular. That's still OK to use BUT you are then required to tell angular when that async operation completes so angular knows to re-evaluate the scope so it can detect what has changed, fire all its bindings and generally work its magic.

Both of the above approaches achieve the same result in the end, they just use different techniques to do it. `$q.defer()` is the promise-style variation and `$scope.$apply` is the callback-style variation, but they are essentially identical in what they do in your example.